# Match everything except a specific pattern in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

After much searching I am still stumped.  How do I match everything in a string except what matches a given pattern.

I have found solutions for negating specific words or character sets using the `^` or negative look ahead, but I need a solution to negate anything that matches a specific pattern.

Example text (snippet of html):

```
abcd efg hijkl <span class='skipMe'>xxx</span> nop qrst uv wxyz.
```

I want to match everything except the whole span tag.  i.e. everything except

```
/<span.*?<\/span>/
```

Any leads are appreciated.

Comment: is your goal to obtain a string without that tag? in that case, you can just do something like: `str.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "")`

Answer (score 1):

You could always split your text on the regex like this:

```js
var text = 'abcd efg hijkl <span class="skipMe">xxx</span> nop qrst uv wxyz.'

console.log(
  text.split(/<span.*?<\/span>/)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log('abcd efg hijkl <span class=\'skipMe\'>xxx</span> nop qrst uv wxyz.'.replace(/<(|\/)span[^>]*>/g, ''));

//OR variant #2

console.log('abcd efg hijkl <span class=\'skipMe\'>xxx</span> nop qrst uv wxyz.'.replace(/\s<span.+span>?/g, ''));
```

[SEE](http://jsbin.com/hucosed/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expressions in this way is extremely naive and prone to unwanted side-effects. My recommendation would be to use the built-in DOM API.

Create a wrapper element, set the value of the `innerHTML` property to the input string, query the wrapper element for the element in question, remove the element in question, then return the value of the `innerHTML` property.

Here's an example:

```js
const input = "abcd efg hijkl <span class='skipMe'>xxx</span> nop qrst uv wxyz.";

const func = input => {
    const wrapper = Object.assign(document.createElement('div'), { innerHTML: input });
    wrapper.querySelector('.skipMe').remove()
    return wrapper.innerHTML;
};

console.log(func(input));
```

One caveat of this approach is that the HTML is passed to the parser, so if the HTML is not valid, [scary things will happen](https://locuststreetpress.files.wordpress.com/2013/09/super-creeper-bunny-meme-generator-scary-things-will-happen-if-you-don-t-follow-the-rules-0e0681.jpg)